# Concatenate a string to each element of an array which is not null

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array like this:
`["name1", "name2", null, null, "name5", null]`

I want to make it like this:

`["name1 wow", "name2 wow", null, null, "name5 wow", null]`

I tried to do it like this:

```
myCtrl.myArray.map(s => s + " wow");
```

Seems it's not the right solution, any ideas?

Comment: Check for nulls.

Comment: Change condition like this `s => s && s + " wow"`

Comment: @Madhavan.V still no effect, the array looks same as before

Comment: `.map` will return new array instead of mutation.

Comment: `myCtrl.myArray = myCtrl.myArray.map(s => s &&  s + " wow")` will work as you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) for checking falsy values and return the falsy value direcly or concat the value with a postfix.

You need to assign the result array of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to a new or the old variable.

```js
var array = ["name1", "name2", null, null, "name5", null],
    result = array.map(s => s && s + " wow");
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I removed the 'wow' string from your input array, obviously a typo, this works great.

Answer (score 3):

Try Aarry's `map()` with  the help of ternary operator like the following:

```js
var arr = ["name1", "name2", null, null, "name5", null];
var res = arr.map(function(item){
  return item != null ? item + ' wow' : null;
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do your adding stuff only if `s` is not null

```
myCtrl.myArray.map(s => (s==null?null:s + " wow"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add condition for `null` checking

```js
let a = ["name1", "name2", null, null, "name5", null];

console.log(a.map(s => s == null ? null : (s + ' wow') ));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, you don't actually have to compare to `null`:

```
var arr = ["name1", "name2", null, null, "name5", null];
var res = arr.map(function(item) {
  return item ? item + ' wow' : null;
});
console.log(res);
```